# Find position of min element of a "masked vector"

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of some values and a mask vector of 0's and 1's. For example:

```
std::vector<int>   mask{0,   0,   1,   0,   1,   1,   0};
std::vector<double> vec{7.1, 1.0, 3.2, 2.0, 1.8, 5.0, 0.0};
```

and I need to find the min element (its index) in `vec` but only where `mask` is 1. In this example it is 1.8 at index 4.

Here's my solution using a loop

```
double minVal = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
int minIndex;
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
{
    if (vec[i] < minVal && mask[i] == 1)
    {
        minVal = vec[i];
        minIndex = i;
    }
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to do it by using the standard library (e.g. `std::min_element` and lambdas), ideally without using the for-loop?

Comment: The `std::min_element` comparator function only takes the values to compare.

Comment: As far as efficiency goes on a single call, there's no real difference between using algorithms or just iterating and checking what you need to check.

Comment: "I need to ..." So what did you try? How did it fail? Please provide a [mre] of your best attempt. Did you at least manage to find the minimum while ignoring the mask?

Comment: You could use a lambda (functor would probably be more clear)  that captures `mask` and tracks state as it iterates through `mask`, but I don't believe `min_element` will handle a non-empty range comparator that contains invalid elements particularly well.

Comment: @infinitezero -- But then you will lose the index of the items from the original vector, which I believe the OP is requesting.

Comment: If you're looking for a function from the standard library than I doubt that there is one. Otherwise I suggest you writing a loop which iterates over the two vectors simultaneously.

Comment: So why did you close the question? It's clear what I am asking.

Comment: Your question is clear, at least to me but please your add failed/not working code to the question. As mentioned in the above comments providing a [mcve] would make your question better assuming there's no dupe.

Comment: Maybe `std::transform` into a combined vector, and then you can use `std::min_element`.

Comment: Thanks for reopening and sorry if it wasn't clear at the beginning.

Comment: @PepijnKramer The question has been reopened. Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: For m the big problem with the question was the now-gone request for an "Efficient" solution. Efficient requires more definition because an efficient runtime may be inefficient with memory usage or difficult, and thus inefficient, to write. Worse, efficient compared to what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can transform into a combined `vector`, using max double as a replacement for masked values, and use that with `std::min_element`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> mask{0,   0,   1,   0,   1,   1,   0};
    std::vector<double> vec{7.1, 1.0, 3.2, 2.0, 1.8, 5.0, 0.0};
    std::vector<double> combined;
    
    std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), mask.begin(),
                   std::back_inserter(combined),
                   [](double v, bool mask) {
                       return mask ? v : std::numeric_limits<double>::max(); });
    
    auto it = std::min_element(combined.begin(), combined.end());
    std::cout << "min=" << *it << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

See https://ideone.com/FncV2r for a live example.

---

Getting the index is fairly easy using `std::distance`

```
std::cout << "index=" << std::distance(combined.begin(), it) << "\n";
```

And applying this to the original vector would be

```
auto index = std::distance(combined.begin(), it);
auto it_vec = vec.begin() + index;
```

See https://ideone.com/U8AXtm

---

Keep in mind, that even though this solution uses std algorithms and a lambda, the questioner's simple for loop is more efficient.

This is because the for loop doesn't need extra space (the combined vector), and finishes in a single run, whereas `transform` and `min_element` take two turns to produce the same result.

So occasionally, there's a time for "old-fashioned" loops.

Comment: Ahh `transform` with int max is clever. Definitely a cleaner/better answer than mine. This will also return int max in the case where the whole mask is OFF.

Comment: "the questioner's simple for loop is more efficient" and I would also add that it is much more readable. Thank you for the answer though, it is interesting!

Answer (score 2):

You can make a helper class that'll combine those vectors into a single vector of structs to make it easy to use `min_element`:

```
template <typename T>
class Masker {
private:
    template <typename V>
    struct Item {
        bool mask;
        V val;
    };
    std::vector<Item<T>> vec;
public:
    Masker(std::vector<bool> mask, std::vector<T> vals) {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++) {
            vec.push_back({mask[i], vals[i]});
        }
    }
    const T& find_min() {
        return (*min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
            [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){ 
                if(!lhs.mask) { return false; }
                if(!rhs.mask) { return true; }
                return lhs.val < rhs.val;
            })).val;
    }
};
```

And then call it like:

```
std::cout << Masker<double>(mask, vec).find_min();
```

Live example: https://ideone.com/G6ymGH

Answer (score 1):

You can create an index vector using `std::iota`. Then use `std::min_element`.

- [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) to generate list of indexes.
- [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) to get the smallest from the given list.

```
int main() {
  std::vector<int> mask{0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0};
  std::vector<double> vec{7.1, 1.0, 3.2, 2.0, 1.8, 5.0, 0.0};
  std::vector<decltype(vec)::size_type> idx(vec.size());
  std::iota(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);

  auto idxmin =
      std::min_element(idx.begin(), idx.end(), [&mask, &vec](auto i, auto j) {
        auto max_v = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
        auto v  = mask[i] ? vec[i] : max_v;
        auto v2 = mask[j] ? vec[j] : max_v;
        return v < v2;
      });

  std::cout << vec[*idxmin] << " at index " << *idxmin; // 1.8 at index 4
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/raadE7nxo)

with [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) we can use [`std::ranges`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges).

- [`std::views::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view) to generate list of indexes.
- [`std::views::filter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view) for filtering out based on a mask.
- [`std::ranges::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/min_element) to find the smallest elements in the given range.

```
int main() {
  std::vector<int> mask{0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0};
  std::vector<double> vec{7.1, 1.0, 3.2, 2.0, 1.8, 5.0, 0.0};
  auto idx = std::views::iota(0lu, vec.size()) |
             std::views::filter([&mask](auto i) { return mask[i] == 1; });
  auto idxmin = std::ranges::min_element(
      idx, [&vec](auto i, auto j) { return vec[i] < vec[j]; });

  std::cout << vec[*idxmin] << " at index " << *idxmin; // 1.8 at index 4
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oM7n7Wsjr)

Answer (score 0):

This is yet another pair of approaches : hand code a loop, or create an intermediate datastructure for use in std::min_element.

```
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

struct entry_t
{
    entry_t(std::size_t i, int m, double v) :
        index{i},
        mask{m},
        value{v}
    {
    }
    
    std::size_t index;
    int mask;
    double value;
};

auto combine(const std::vector<int>& mask, const std::vector<double>& values)
{
    if (mask.size() != values.size()) throw std::invalid_argument("vector sizes don't match");
    
    std::vector<entry_t> entries;

    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < values.size(); ++n)
    {
        entries.emplace_back(n, mask[n], values[n]);
    }
    
    return entries;
}


auto find_masked_min_index(const std::vector<int>& mask, const std::vector<double>& values)
{
    if (mask.size() != values.size()) throw std::invalid_argument("vector sizes don't match");

    double min = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    std::size_t index = 0;

    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < values.size(); ++n)
    {
        if ((mask[n] == 1) && (values[n] < min))
        {
            index = n;
            min = values[n];
        }
    }

    return index;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int>   mask{ 0,   0,   1,   0,   1,   1,   0 };
    std::vector<double> vec{ 7.1, 1.0, 3.2, 2.0, 1.8, 5.0, 0.0 };

    // method one, hand coded
    auto index = find_masked_min_index(mask, vec);
    std::cout << "Minimum is at index : " << index << ", value = " << vec[index] << "\n";

    // method two, create a combined datastructure 
    auto combined = combine(mask, vec);

    // use std::min_element
    auto it = std::min_element(combined.begin(), combined.end(), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs)
    {
        return ((lhs.mask == 1) && (lhs.value < rhs.value));
    });

    std::cout << "Minimum is at index : " << it->index << ", value = " << it->value << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```